# name 'Application' not defined

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm trying to open an excel workbook and run a macro using python. However, the macro exists in my Personal Macro Library and I need to run it from there. When I try to do that I got the following error:

"Cannot run the macro Macro may not be available in this workbook..."

To remedy this problem, I used Application.run() hoping that this would allow me to run a macro not present in the workbook I am trying to run it on. However, when I do this I get another error:

"name 'Application' is not defined"

Here is my code below. It's real simple.

```py
.
.
.
# Open workbook
wb2 = xw.Book('C:/Users/AChakrav/Documents/LTspiceXVII/Circuits/INV/INVAMP_MEAS_Script.xlsm')
time.sleep(5)

Application.Run "'PERSONAL.XLSB'!CompiledTableGenerator"
#ExcelMacro_2 = wb2.macro('PERSONAL.XLSB!CompiledTableGenerator')
#ExcelMacro_2()
time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the problem from a **different angle** - e.g., try to refer the `Personal.xlsb` file in Python and give it a try from there.  E.g., to locate it, run this in the immediate window in VBA:

```
?Application.StartupPath
```

and hardcode it later in the Python code.

Then write something simple as this one in `Personal.xlsb`:

[image]

In Python, install `pipiwin32` and run the code like this:

```
import win32com.client

xl=win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
xl.Workbooks.Open('C:\\Users\\gropc\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Excel\\XLSTART\\Personal.xlsb')
xl.Application.Run('Personal.xlsb!Modul1.SomeApplication')
```

The message box with the date and time will show up. The VBA code should be well written, to make sure it refers correctly the workbooks you need, but this is another issue.

Comment: I tried what you are suggesting and I am able to open the personal workbook and run a macro. I have no problem running a macro that exists in the active workbook. The problem is running a macro that exists in the personal workbook from another active workbook.